# Como excluir uma tabela da "memória" do SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Eu tinha uma tabela chamado tb_estado em um banco de dados SQL Server e a exclui, ao tentar criar uma tabela com o mesmo nome o sistema retornar erro informando que ela já existe, como faço para apagar a tabela da memória do banco ?

Comment: Vc excluiu pela interface ou por código ? Estranho pq isso eu nunca vi acontecer

Comment: Via interface, o mesmo erro ocorre com as stored procedures.

Comment: cara ja tento por código? drop table nome_tabela

Comment: Tentei sim, ele informa que excluiu, mas ao tentar salvar retorna erro.

Comment: Então, para funcionar tive que fechar e abrir o sql server. Todas vez que excluo um objeto do banco preciso abrir e fechar a aplicação.

Comment: Veja se ajuda : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9792379/drop-table-in-sql-server-by-sql-server-management-studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inicie sempre as suas consultas com: USE [NomedoBanco]
Se você estiver usando o Management Studio, verifique na campo "Evitar Salvar alterações..." em Ferramenta/Opções/Design está desmarcada.

[image: Ferramentas'/Opções]

Comment: Uma outra dica: